# Unable to execute command: Killed

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, swift3

I'm using IBM's [online Swift sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl) and I'm trying to run this code but it's giving me an error:

**The code:**

```
var a: Double = 1.0
var b: Double = 2.0
var c: Double = 3.0
var x: Double = 0.0

func x_func(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

  x = (-b + (b^2 - 4*a*c)^(1/2))/(2*a)
  return x

}

print(x_func(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

**The error:**

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Killed
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong? I'm brand new to Swift, so I don't see an error here.

Comment: The swift repl says: `error: repl.swift:8:5: error: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
  x = (-b + (b^2 - 4*a*c)^(1/2))/(2*a)`

Comment: Oh ok. How did you see that message?

Comment: @Pierce using `pow` gives me the error :`use of unresolved identifier 'pow'`

Comment: Never mind, looks like I just needed to import Foundation

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment and just posted an answer because I needed to include more code than would be practical for one line. I assume you're trying to do exponents right? If so see my answer below. If NOT - please let me know so I can delete it

Comment: @whatwhatwhat What's the point of taking variables as input parameters if you don't use them in your function?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `pow` when you want to use exponents, the `^` doesn't work with Swift for that. With Swift `^` produces bitwise XOR - not exponent.

```
import Foundation

var a: Double = 1.0
var b: Double = 2.0
var c: Double = 3.0
var x: Double = 0.0

func x_func(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

    x = (-b + pow((pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c), 1/2))/2*a
    return x

}
```

Make sure when using things like IBM Sandbox, or HackerRank or whatever to import Foundation framework! I know it's easy to forget and can cause a lot of headache if you do.

Also, unless you're doing extra computation in your `x_func` method that you're not showing, you're asking for parameters to be passed in that you don't even use. You can either get rid of the properties, or change the function to not take in any variables - it would probably be more efficient to get rid of the properties and change it to something like this:

```
import Foundation

func x_func(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> Double {

    x = (-b + pow((pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c), 1/2))/2*a
    return x

}
```

Comment: This is not working in IBM's online compiler.

Comment: @AntonMalmygin - did you import Foundation?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. Thanks