# How can I test for the error in machine precision as I change the value of the variable `c`?

Tags: swift, precision, subtraction, rounding-error

I'm following Landau's *A Survey of Computational Physics* and I am doing this problem (part b):

[image]

I've written code to generate the 4 solutions below. I'm confused as to what the author wants me to do here.

1. When testing for subtractive cancellation errors, is it as simple as subtracting result 1 from result 2? The point is to see how a machine screws up subtraction due to rounding, so there is no way I can get the exact answer from a machine, right?
2. For my solution to this, I found that using `c=10^-1` results in `1.38777878078145e-17` for method 1 and `1.11022302462516e-16` for method 2. When I crank it up to `c=10^-16` (without getting `inf` as a result), I get `-1.10223024625156e-17` for method 1 and `-0.0992800745259007` for method 2. This tells me that for method 2 there was a very large change in value as I modified `c`. But I don't think I'm grasping the essence of what the author wants me to understand here.

**If you want to see the code, here it is. Otherwise, you can see some sample output below:**

```
import Foundation

var a: Double = 1.0
var b: Double = 1.0
var c: Double = pow(10,-16)
var x: Double = 0.0

//The following variables are just used to run the calculations within 
//the functions, i.e. they can be reused within each function definition
var x1: Double = 0.0
var x2: Double = 0.0

func x_func(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

    x1 = 0.0
    x2 = 0.0
    x = 0.0

    x1 = pow(b,2.0)-4.0*a*c
    x2 = -b + x1.squareRoot()
    x = x2/(2.0*a)  

    return x

}
func x_func2(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

    x1 = 0.0
    x2 = 0.0
    x = 0.0

    x1 = pow(b,2.0)-4.0*a*c
    x2 = -b - x1.squareRoot()
    x = x2/(2.0*a)  

    return x

}
func xp_func(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

    x1 = 0.0
    x2 = 0.0
    x = 0.0

    x1 = pow(b,2.0)-4.0*a*c
    x2 = x1.squareRoot() + b
    x = -2.0*c/x2

    return x

}
func xp_func2(a_var: Double, b_var: Double, c_var: Double) -> Double {

    x1 = 0.0
    x2 = 0.0
    x = 0.0

    x1 = pow(b,2.0)-4.0*a*c
    x2 = b - x1.squareRoot()
    x = -2.0*c/x2

    return x

}

print("Method 1: Positive")
print(x_func(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))
print(" \n")



print("Method 1: Negative")
print(x_func2(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))
print(" \n")



print("Method 2: Positive")
print(xp_func(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))
print(" \n")



print("Method 2: Negative")
print(xp_func2(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))

print(" \n")

print("Subtractive cancellation error for Method 1:")
print(" \n")
print("Method 1 (positive) minus Method 2 (positive)",x_func(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c) - xp_func(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))

print(" \n")
print("Subtractive cancellation error for Method 2:")
print(" \n")
print("Method 1 (negative) minus Method 2 (negative)",x_func2(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c) - xp_func2(a_var: a, b_var: b, c_var: c))
```

**Sample output:**

```
Method 1: Positive
-1.11022302462516e-16

Method 1: Negative
-1.0

Method 2: Positive
-1e-16

Method 2: Negative
-0.900719925474099

Subtractive cancellation error for Method 1:

Method 1 (positive) minus Method 2 (positive) -1.10223024625156e-17

Subtractive cancellation error for Method 2:

Method 1 (negative) minus Method 2 (negative) -0.0992800745259007
```

Comment: Is this a question about Swift programming or about understanding numerical mathematics?

Comment: You may also want to read this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027328/unable-to-execute-command-killed#comment71229675_42027328 to your previous question again, and learn about *local variables* (instead of defining `x1`, `x2` globally).

Comment: I tagged swift because that's the language that I'm using but my focus is to understand how errors occur in computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us simplify your code. You have two methods to compute
the solutions of the quadratic equation `a x^2 + b x + c == 0`:

```
func qsolve1(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    let x1 = (-b - (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())/(2*a)
    let x2 = (-b + (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())/(2*a)
    return (x1, x2)
}

func qsolve2(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    let x1 = -2*c/(b - (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())
    let x2 = -2*c/(b + (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())
    return (x1, x2)
}
```

(We are only considering the case `a != 0`, `c != 0` and `b^2 - 4ac >= 0` here.)

Both methods would return the same results if the computations were done
exactly, but due to the floating point rounding errors they are different.

Applied to the polynomial

```
x^2 + x + 1.0E-10
```

you get the results:

```
print(qsolve1(a: 1.0, b: 1.0, c: 1.0E-10))
// (-0.99999999989999999, -1.000000082740371e-10)

print(qsolve2(a: 1.0, b: 1.0, c: 1.0E-10))
// (-0.99999991725963588, -1.0000000001000001e-10)
```

If we compare those numbers with the results from PARI/GP

```
? solve(x=-1.5, -0.5, x^2+x+1.0e-10)
%2 = -0.99999999989999999998999999999800000000
? solve(x=-0.5, +0.5, x^2+x+1.0e-10)
%3 = -1.0000000001000000000200000000050000000 E-10
```

then we see that `qsolve1()` computes the solution near `-1.0`
more precisely, and `qsolve2()` computes the solution near `0.0`
more precisely.

**Why does that happen?** Let us inspect the intermediate results:

```
print("b=", b.debugDescription, " sqrt(b^2-4ac)=", (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot().debugDescription)
// b= 1.0  sqrt(b^2-4ac)= 0.99999999979999998
```

A binary floating point number has a limited precision, about
16 decimal digits for IEEE 754 double precision numbers.

When computing `x1` in `qsolve1()` or `x2` in `qsolve2()`, those
two numbers are *subtracted,* and the difference is approximately

```
0.00000000020000002
```

which has only 8 significant digits, and not 16 anymore. That is the
"subtractive cancellation" and it happens when two numbers of about
the same value are subtracted from each other.

It is therefore numerically better to *add* the numbers. Whether
`x1` or `x2` are more precise depends on the sign of `b`. In any
case, the other solution can be computes from the relation
`x1 * x2 = c` without loss of precision.

That gives the following method:

```
func qsolve(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    let x1: Double
    if b >= 0 {
        x1 = (-b - (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())/(2*a)
    } else {
        x1 = (-b + (b*b - 4*a*c).squareRoot())/(2*a)
    }
    let x2 = c/x1
    return (x1, x2)
}
```

and for our test case we get

```
print(qsolve(a: 1.0, b: 1.0, c: 1.0E-10))
// (-0.99999999989999999, -1.0000000001000001e-10)
```

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: A (free) computer algebra system. I used it only for comparison.

Comment: So then how do I define the "computation error" here (as per the question in the book)? Would I say that it is simply `b*b - 4*a*c`? Because this is the value that changes as I change the value of `c`.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: "Computation error" is the difference between the computed and the exact solution.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case I'll look into this PARI/GP program to get more precise values. By any chance, do you know how to make swift show the exact machine epsilon? I heard there was a function for this but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: `print(Double.ulpOfOne)` in Swift 3.

Comment: Wait, but during calculations I'm getting 17 digits after the decimal place. However, when I use `print(Double.ulpOfOne)` it returns `2.22044604925031e-16`, which only has 14 digits after the decimal place. How can the machine's set precision be lower than what it's actually returning in a calculation?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: `ulpOfOne` is the difference between 1.0 and the next larger machine number. How this number is *printed* (and with how many digits) is a different thing.